# Rails session, how to set SameSite to Lax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies, ruby-on-rails-6

In Rails 6.0.3.1 Is there a way to natively set the Rails session cookie same site attribute without resorting to using a gem such as [the secure headers gem](https://github.com/github/secure_headers)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw this `before_action` in your ApplicationController:

```
response.headers['SameSite'] = 'Lax'
```

Edit: my answer was for Rails 5.2, and *wrong*. Setting `same_site: :lax` in your **session_store.rb** file *does* work.

Comment: To tighten up the Rails 5.2 answer that worked for me as well. My config/initilizers/session_store.rb looks like this:       `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'myKey', same_site: :strict `

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a solution to my specific problem so I upgraded my application to use Rails 6.1 which has a new initializer file called new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb which has the following. self explanatory comments that solve my issue.
I do NOT believe that every single Rails application should upgrade to Rails 6.1 to solve this and Rails team need to solve this urgently so I am posting my answer but not accepting it in the hope that someone may have a more appropriate answer for anyone else looking to solve this.

```
# Specify cookies SameSite protection level: either :none, :lax, or :strict.
#
# This change is not backwards compatible with earlier Rails versions.
# It's best enabled when your entire app is migrated and stable on 6.1.
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :lax
```